# Dynamic Class Generation With Sass

Tags: sass

I want to create my own bootsrap with flexbox.It is something like this:

```
.df {
  display: flex;
}
.aic {
  align-items: center;
}
.jcc {
  justify-content: center;
}
.jcsb {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.fdc {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fx1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

But there is also one thing I would like to realize,that's dynamic classes for margins and paddings and etc.Something like:

```
.mr-40 {
margin-right: 40;
}
```

So i want to this value (40) to be dynamic (1,5,100 and so on).Is there a way to realize this in SCSS/SASS?

Comment: Could u elaborate on how to make it dynamic? Like a list of values it's going to iterate through?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick implementation:

```sass
@use "sass:map";

$utils: (
   "padding": (
      "className": p,
      "property": padding,
      "values": 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 90 100,
   ),
   "margin": (
      "className": m,
      "property": padding,
      "values": 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 90 100,
   ),
);

@each $key, $values in $utils {
   @each $cValue in map.get($values, "values") {
      .#{map.get($values, "className")}-#{$cValue} {
         #{map.get($values, "property")}: $cValue + "px";
      }
   }
}
```

```sass
.p-0 {
  padding: "0px";
}

.p-10 {
  padding: "10px";
}

.p-20 {
  padding: "20px";
}

// ...

.m-0 {
  padding: "0px";
}

// ...
```